# Error in SQL Statement using INSERT and AUTO-INCREMENT column

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `configuration` VALUES ('', 'News Box Character Count', 'NEWS_BOX_CHAR_COUNT', '200', 'Set the number of characters (bytes) that you want to display in the news preview box.', 19, 99, NULL, '2004-09-07 12:00:00', NULL, NULL);
```

I run this command in phpMyAdmin, it shows

```
#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'configuration_id' at row 1
```

`configuration_id` is an auto increment field beginnning of 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this `INSERT INTO configuration VALUES ('', 'News Box Character Count',`

Pass the value as `NULL` for auto_increment or integer column or you can simply not to include that column in sql query.

```
INSERT INTO `configuration` VALUES (NULL, 'News Box Character Count', ...
```

This is because, mysql is running in the strict mode.

You can either use `NULL` for all the integer columns when there is nothing to enter them or turn off the MySql Strict mode.

Comment: +1 for mentioning strict mode - without that turned on, the original query would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

For an [autoincrement in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), either **insert NULL** or insert nothing at all:

#### Easiest & Cleanest: using NULL

```
INSERT INTO `configuration` VALUES (NULL, 'News Box Character Count', 'NEWS_BOX_CHAR_COUNT', '200', 'Set the number of characters (bytes) that you want to display in the news preview box.', 19, 99, NULL, '2004-09-07 12:00:00', NULL, NULL);
```

#### More work: name every column except the autoincrement one

```
INSERT INTO `configuration` (every,column,except,the,first) VALUES ('News Box Charac`ter Count', 'NEWS_BOX_CHAR_COUNT', '200', 'Set the number of characters (bytes) that you want to display in the news preview box.', 19, 99, NULL, '2004-09-07 12:00:00', NULL, NULL);`
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty obvious to me? You gave an integer column and you are explicitly inserting a string (although it's empty). If the column is set to auto increment, remove the first value ('') from your values array and you should be fine. Also, maybe you wanto to specify the columns you are inserting values for, like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the AUTO_INCREMENT field you can set NULL; it will generate new value automatically.

For example -

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(NULL, 'value', ...)...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is auto-increment then you can simple omit it from the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the '' value with NULL ('' isn't a valid integer). See [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,183309,183352#msg-183352).

Answer (score 0):

You should always use column names when inserting. So just don't have to insert into the column configuration_id and your sql statement doesn't break when changing the columns.

Use something like this: `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);`