# AUTO_INCREMENT requires a value when inserting, but only sometimes

Tags: mysql, percona

I am using MySQL (`Percona 5.5.34-32.0`) and I have this table;

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE privmsgs\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: privmsgs
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `privmsgs` (
  `msg_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `root_level` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `author_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `icon_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `author_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enable_bbcode` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `enable_smilies` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `enable_magic_url` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `enable_sig` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `message_subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message_text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `message_edit_reason` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message_edit_user` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_attachment` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bbcode_bitfield` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bbcode_uid` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message_edit_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_edit_count` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_address` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `bcc_address` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
  KEY `author_ip` (`author_ip`),
  KEY `message_time` (`message_time`),
  KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
  KEY `root_level` (`root_level`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5238652 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

I have this modes enabled for the whole session:

```
mysql> SELECT @@session.sql_mode\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@session.sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

When I try to insert something, this happens:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO privmsgs
    ->   (root_level, author_id, icon_id, author_ip, message_time,
    ->    enable_bbcode, enable_smilies, enable_magic_url, enable_sig,
    ->    message_subject, message_text, message_attachment, bbcode_bitfield,
    ->    bbcode_uid, to_address, bcc_address)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (0, 12345, 0, '127.0.0.0', 123456789, 1, 1, 0, 0, 'test',
    ->    'testing message', 0, '', 'xxx', 'u_12345', '');
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'msg_id' doesn't have a default value
```

The weirdest thing is that if I create another table running the exact same output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE privmsgs` that I pasted before (but obviously changing its name to something else, like `privmsgs2`), **I can run the exact same query without any errors or warnings**:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO privmsgs2
    ->   (root_level, author_id, icon_id, author_ip, message_time,
    ->    enable_bbcode, enable_smilies, enable_magic_url, enable_sig,
    ->    message_subject, message_text, message_attachment, bbcode_bitfield,
    ->    bbcode_uid, to_address, bcc_address)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (0, 12345, 0, '127.0.0.0', 123456789, 1, 1, 0, 0, 'test',
    ->    'testing message', 0, '', 'xxx', 'u_12345', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

What is going on?!

Note that disabling `STRICT_*` modes is not the solution I'm looking for: it's not clean, and the fact that **I can run the exact same query on another identical table in the same session** suggests (?) that the problem might not be there.

Comment: It's because you're in STRICT mode. Just add msg_id and NULL to your INSERT . As such this is a... possible duplicate of [Error in SQL Statement using INSERT and AUTO-INCREMENT column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899676/error-in-sql-statement-using-insert-and-auto-increment-column)

Comment: Please read the full question: I know that disabling STRICT mode solves it. But why does it work in a table and not in other?

Comment: I think @strawberry gave you the answer, INSERT cannot guess that your msg_id is undefined, you need to till it is. This is how AUTO_INCREMENT works, you provide NULL as the value for the auto increment field. In some cases MySQL is smart enough to guess it.

Comment: Aha! We are progressing now with the point of my question, @nrathaus :) "In some cases MySQL is smart enough to guess it". Do you know if this is documented, even if as undefined behavior? That'd certainly explain it.

Comment: Your DDLs/DMLs show the first scenario only. We know that doesn't work, and we know why. You haven't provided CREATE and INSERTs for the second scenario.

Comment: What about this? http://i.imgur.com/PqdwSA5.png In that screenshot you can *see* that I am in strict mode and that I can insert data "the wrong way" (that is, without specifying the column name and a NULL value). That's why the error surprised me and made me post this question in the first place :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here are the facts:

- This is the table of a phpBB installation which **has been working perfectly for a long time** with MySQL Percona.
- When connecting, by default the application sets the `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` and `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` modes, and has been doing that for a long time too.
- Of all the tables the application uses, **this is the only one where the described inconsistent behavior appears**.
- When creating another table pasting the `SHOW CREATE TABLE privmsgs` output, the new table **didn't show** this behavior. When using `CREATE TABLE privmsgs2 FROM privmsgs`, **it did**.
- Downgrading to Oracle's MySQL 5.5.31 didn't change any of these facts.

I tried reconstructing the table with `ALTER TABLE privmsgs ENGINE=InnoDB`, [according official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rebuilding-tables.html), but that didn't help.

So I dumped the table with `mysqldump databasename privmsgs > table.sql`, changed its name to `privmsgs2` in the file with `sed` and then reimported it with `mysql databasename < table.sql`. Then I dropped `privmsgs` and renamed `privmsgs2` to `privmsgs`.

**Then it started working perfectly again**. I don't understand why and couldn't find any other reference to this behavior. If somebody is able to explain it with a more precise answer than mine, please do it and I'll accept your answer.