# What is the right way of inserting datetime in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

This is my FLIGHT table when I insert in it I get error but I have tried to look online, I cannot see anything wrong with my code.

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT
(
  ID INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FLIGHT_NUMBER VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL, 
  OPERATING_AIRLINES VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  DEPARTURE_CITY VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  ARRIVAL_CITY VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  DATE_OF_DEPARTURE DATE  NOT NULL,
  ESTIMATED_DEPARTURE_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

id,arrival_city,date_of_departure,departure_city,estimated_departure_time,flight_number,operating_airlines

```sql
insert into flight values(9,'SW3','South West','NYC',
'DAL',STR_TO_DATE('06/20/2020 10:14:07', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'),'06/20/2020 10:14:07')
```

When I highlight and Execute the above lines,
I get this error below:

```
 'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('06-19-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'),'06-19-2020 03:14:07') Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: 'American Airlines' for column 'date_of_departure' at row 1 0.016 sec
```

Comment: Show the table schema. If one actually reads the error, it seems you missed or added an expression in the `insert` and are trying to put a string into a date column. Not only that, but th error quotes a string that doesn't exist in your code, so you must be running something other than what you posted.

Comment: Thanks underscore_d but i think now this info is understandable

Comment: Thatnks for adding the schema, but you still quote an error that includes a string value that doesn't exist in your quoted query, and how can that possibly happen unless one or both of those quotes are incorrect/outdated?

Comment: I really don't know why i get this error, I have just reinserted even now.

Comment: insert into flight values(1,'AA1','American Airlines','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('06-19-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'),'06-19-2020 03:14:07')

Comment: And this is the error again.

Comment: 0 4 13:37:06 insert into flight values(1,'AA1','American Airlines','AUS',
 'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('06-19-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'),'06-19-2020 03:14:07') Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: 'American Airlines' for column 'date_of_departure' at row 1 0.016 sec

Comment: Thanks, so please [edit] the question to include the latest/matching code and error.

Comment: Anyway, you probably just need to specify the columns to insert, to match each element in the `values` collection, and don't give an explicit value for an `auto_increment` column for obvious reasons. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899676/error-in-sql-statement-using-insert-and-auto-increment-column

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have included columns and removed id value

Comment: now the error has changed

Comment: This is the insert query

Comment: insert into flight (flight_number, 
operating_airlines,departure_city,arrival_city,date_of_departure,
estimated_departure_time
) values('AA1','American Airlines','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('06-19-2020 03:14:07', '%m-%d-%Y %H:$i:%s'),'06-19-2020 03:14:07')

Comment: This is the error now:

Comment: 0 20 14:12:19 insert into flight (flight_number, 
 operating_airlines,departure_city,arrival_city,date_of_departure,
 estimated_departure_time
 ) values('AA1','American Airlines','AUS',
 'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('06-19-2020 03:14:07', '%m-%d-%Y %H:$i:%s'),'06-19-2020 03:14:07') Error Code: 1364. Field 'id' doesn't have a default value 0.015 sec

Comment: when I put back the id value, then i get the original error

Comment: You cannot be running against the schema you actually show, because of course an `auto_increment` has a default value; in fact, it should have _only_ default values. Can't reproduce: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c651af/1) This is really all quite a waste of time!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running this in SQL Fiddle and found that your date formats were invalid, causing an error, and the `STR_TO_DATE()` is unnecessary and noisy.

Also, you shouldn't pass explicit values for `auto_increment` columns because, well, they're meant to auto-increment themselves. It seemed to work for me even if I did pass `1`, but the advice is to pass `null` and let the engine assign.

This amended schema [builds/runs just fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/567c0ee/1):

```sql
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT
(
  ID INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FLIGHT_NUMBER VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL, 
  OPERATING_AIRLINES VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  DEPARTURE_CITY VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  ARRIVAL_CITY VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  DATE_OF_DEPARTURE DATE  NOT NULL,
  ESTIMATED_DEPARTURE_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into flight
values (
  null,
  'SW3',
  'South West',
  'NYC',
  'DAL',
  '2020-06-20',
  '2020-06-20 10:14:07'
);
```

Alternatively, you say the below worked, although I still don't see why it allows you to pass an explicit value of your `id` is *really* an `auto_increment` field, but hey...

To avoid specifying `id` at all (`null` or not), you could use the below but without the 1st line in each of the columns or `values` sets.

```sql
insert into flight (
  id,
  flight_number,
  operating_airlines,
  departure_city,
  arrival_city,
  date_of_departure,
  estimated_departure_time
)
values (
  1,
  'SW3',
  'South West',
  'NYC',
  'DAL',
  '2020-06-20 10:14:07',
  '2020-06-20 10:14:07'
);
```